# kubectl tls secret automatisation

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use tls secret on gke ingress (gpc LB7) and I'm stuck. To be clear I can create the tls secret using the kubectl command:

```
kubectl create secret tls wildcard-cert --cert fullchain.pem --key private.pem
```

That works just fine, but for automatisation purpose, I would like to be able to deploy the secret from a yaml file using the same files, those are wildcard used in more than one place and stored in a secret engine.

I can't use secretgenerator as it doesn't seems to support tls and the secret type tls doesn't seems to be able to take files.

What I would like to be able to create:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wildcard-cert
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: fullchain.pem
  tls.key: private.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use secretGenerator as I don't think nginx cares if it's a TLS or Opaque secret.  A TLS secret is really just an Opaque secret with a known layout.

Rename your key/cert files:  `fullchain.pem` to `tls.crt` and `private.pem` to `tls.key`.

Using secretGenerator:

```
secretGenerator:
- name: wildcard-cert
  files:
  - tls.crt
  - tls.key
```

Which should generate a Secret like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wildcard-cert
data:
  tls.crt: |
        MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
  tls.key: |
        MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7yn3bRHQ5FHMQ ...
```

which should work with GKE Ingress.

**EDIT:**

Note that

`kubectl create secret tls wildcard-cert --cert fullchain.pem --key private.pem`

will actually create a secret that looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: wildcard-cert
    type: kubernetes.io/tls
    data:
      tls.crt: |
            MIIC2DCCAcCgAwIBAgIBATANBgkqh ...
      tls.key: |
            MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA7yn3bRHQ5FHMQ ....
```

which should be equivalent to what secretGenerator generated for all practical purposes.

Comment: I edited my question to be clearer, I'm putting the cert on an ingress resource, not on an nginx pod.

Comment: this should work even with that.  I don't think the `type: kubernetes.io/tls` is actually required .. it really just the format that matters.  Even `type: kubernetes.io/tls` will actually have the cert and key contents embedded.  `kubectl` just lets you specify files to obtain the content for the Secret.

Comment: the diff: the latter has "type: kubernetes.io/tls".